# Java stream toList - why we use Arraylist twice?

Tags: java, java-stream

Does anyone know the reason behind why Java Stream's `toList()` method implementation is like this?

```
default List<T> toList() {
    return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())));
}
```

That is - why `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` ? It could have been simply like this.

```
default List<T> toList() {
    return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(this.toArray()));
}
```

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) of `asList()`: Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. Changes made to the array will be visible in the returned list," - so using `new ArrayList()` *decouples* the array from the list, that is, if the array get changed, the list is not affected

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting to see a similar question.